# ORDER BY varchar column

Tags: mysql

I have a colum in my database that contains numbers in the format

1-1
1-2
2-1
2-2
etc

I want to be able to order by "first number", "second_number"

I have tried this:

```
ORDER BY CAST('session_number' as signed) ASC
```

But thats not ordering the second number correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by first part by taking substring and casting to signed:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(session_number, '-', 1) AS SIGNED) ASC, 
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(session_number, '-', -1) AS SIGNED) ASC
```

Or create view of already sorted items:

```
CREATE VIEW v_sessions_ordered_by_session_number 
AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM sessions 
  ORDER BY 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(session_number, '-', 1) AS SIGNED) ASC, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(session_number, '-', -1) AS SIGNED) ASC;
```

and then use Your view as table:

```
SELECT some_field, session_number FROM v_sessions_ordered_by_session_number;
```

But **better solution** is:

make `session_number` to be decimal like: `1.1`, `1.2`, `2.1` and etc

if modification of field type not allowed then just

create extra: `session_number_order` field and keep decimalized data

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select nums
from (
    select nums, position('-' in nums) `pos` from tbl
) a
order by cast(substring(nums, 1, pos - 1) as signed),
         cast(substring(nums, pos + 1, length(nums) - pos) as signed)
```

In `order by` clause, firstly you order by first number (before the dash `-`), secondary ordering is according to second number (after the dash).